# Changing the selected option of an HTML Select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my HTML, I have a `<select>` with three `<option>` elements.  I want to use jQuery to check each option's value against a Javascript `var`.  If one matches, I want to set the selected attribute of that option.  How would I do that?

Comment: Post your HTML. But in usual way: `$('#myselectid').val()`

Comment: Not sure why he was downvoted, he's a new user and the question seems legit.

Answer (score 377):

### Vanilla JavaScript

Using plain old JavaScript:

```js
var val = "Fish";
var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  var opts = sel.options;
  for (var opt, j = 0; opt = opts[j]; j++) {
    if (opt.value == val) {
      sel.selectedIndex = j;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="sel">
    <option>Cat</option>
    <option>Dog</option>
    <option>Fish</option>
</select>
<button id="btn">Select Fish</button>
```

### jQuery

But if you *really* want to use jQuery:

```
var val = 'Fish';
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('#sel').val(val);
});
```

```js
var val = 'Fish';
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('#sel').val(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel">
    <option>Cat</option>
    <option>Dog</option>
    <option>Fish</option>
</select>
<button id="btn">Select Fish</button>
```

### jQuery - Using Value Attributes

In case your options have value attributes which differ from their text content and you want to select via text content:

```
<select id="sel">
    <option value="1">Cat</option>
    <option value="2">Dog</option>
    <option value="3">Fish</option>
</select>
<script>
    var val = 'Fish';
    $('#sel option:contains(' + val + ')').prop({selected: true});
</script>
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kaleb/GFS2f/165/)

But if you do have the above set up and want to select by value using jQuery, you can do as before:

```
var val = 3;
$('#sel').val(val);
```

### Modern DOM

For the browsers that support [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector) and the [`HTMLOptionElement::selected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement#Properties) property, this is a more succinct way of accomplishing this task:

```
var val = 3;    
document.querySelector('#sel [value="' + val + '"]').selected = true;
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kaleb/GFS2f/518/)

### [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/)

```
<select data-bind="value: val">
    <option value="1">Cat</option>
    <option value="2">Dog</option>
    <option value="3">Fish</option>
</select>
<script>
    var viewModel = {
        val: ko.observable()
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    viewModel.val(3);
</script>
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GFS2f/577/)

### [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/)

```
<template id="template" is="dom-bind">
    <select value="{{ val }}">
        <option value="1">Cat</option>
        <option value="2">Dog</option>
        <option value="3">Fish</option>
    </select>
</template>
<script>
    template.val = 3;
</script>
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kaleb/GFS2f/884/)

### [Angular 2](https://angular.io/)

Note: this has not been updated for the final stable release.

```
<app id="app">
    <select [value]="val">
        <option value="1">Cat</option>
        <option value="2">Dog</option>
        <option value="3">Fish</option>
    </select>
</app>
<script>
    var App = ng.Component({selector: 'app'})
        .View({template: app.innerHTML})
        .Class({constructor:  function() {}});

    ng.bootstrap(App).then(function(app) {
        app._hostComponent.instance.val = 3;
    });
</script>
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kaleb/GFS2f/956/)

### [Vue 2](https://vuejs.org/)

```
<div id="app">
    <select v-model="val">
        <option value="1">Cat</option>
        <option value="2">Dog</option>
        <option value="3">Fish</option>
    </select>
</div>
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
                val: null,
        },
        mounted: function() {
                this.val = 3;
        }
    });
</script>
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kaleb/GFS2f/1221/)

Comment: This was especially useful because I wasn't sure how to set the selected attribute.  I didn't realize there was a selectedIndex.  Thanks.

Comment: @llihttocs :-( how about now?

Comment: @aelgoa http://jsperf.com/option-select-loop/2 I corrected your first snippet to more mimic my code, which makes mine slower. I used post-increment instead of pre-increment, and then I added another test which is slightly faster than your 3rd test.

Comment: for the sadistic: `document.evaluate(".//select[@id='sel']/option[text()='Fish']", document.body, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.selected = true;`

Comment: @llihttocs What about now?

Comment: @llihttocs I'll try and expand this a little more for you.

Comment: How to get the change callback to work? <select onchange="not-firing">

Comment: @CoreyAlix this is probably suited for another question. Link it here.

Comment: Thank you for including vanilla javascript - for those of us who love to code for ourselves :)

Comment: Impressive, and especially for showing the principles behind how this works, not just answering the singular question. Thank you. In particular I appreciate the efforts in posting a Vanilla-JS and  a "modern" query selector solution.

Answer (score 27):

None of the examples using jquery in here are actually correct as they will leave the select displaying the first entry even though value has been changed.

The right way to select Alaska and have the select show the right item as selected using:

```
<select id="state">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>
```

With jquery would be:

```
$('#state').val('AK').change();
```

Answer (score 26):

You can change the value of the select element, which changes the selected option to the one with that value, using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('sel').value = 'bike';​​​​​​​​​​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/xkqTR/1413/)

Comment: Your example doesn't quite work because of timing.  I updated it to wait until user clicks a button:  http://jsfiddle.net/xkqTR/3271/

Comment: this does not fire change event on select element. do you have solution on that?

Answer (score 10):

#### Markup

```
<select id="my_select">
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>
```

#### jQuery

```
var my_value = 2;
$('#my_select option').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this); // cache this jQuery object to avoid overhead

    if ($this.val() == my_value) { // if this option's value is equal to our value
        $this.prop('selected', true); // select this option
        return false; // break the loop, no need to look further
    }
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/yU6uT/)

Comment: I think this is exactly what I needed.  I have already used several lines of your code and it seems to work.  Thanks for the great snippets.

Comment: @llihttocs: Glad I helped. Feel free to accept the answer which solves your problem by clicking the empty tick below the vote count on the top left hand side of the answer. So that this question gets marked as resolved and others who will be looking for the same solution will find the answer easily.

Answer (score 4):

I want to change the select element's selected option's both value & textContent (what we see) to 'Mango'.

Simplest code that worked is below:

```
var newValue1 = 'Mango'

var selectElement = document.getElementById('myselectid');
selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value = newValue1;
selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].textContent = newValue1;
```

Answer (score 3):

I used almost all of the answers posted here but not comfortable with that so i dig one step furter and found easy solution that fits my need and feel worth sharing with you guys.
Instead of iteration all over the options or using **JQuery** you can do using core **JS** in simple steps:

**Example**

```
<select id="org_list">
  <option value="23">IBM</option>
  <option value="33">DELL</option>
  <option value="25">SONY</option>
  <option value="29">HP</option>
</select>
```

So you must know the value of the option to select.

```
function selectOrganization(id){
    org_list=document.getElementById('org_list');
    org_list.selectedIndex=org_list.querySelector('option[value="'+id+'"]').index;
}
```

How to Use?

```
selectOrganization(25); //this will select SONY from option List
```

Your comments are welcome. :) AzmatHunzai.

Answer (score 2):

[Test this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yT5qW/2/)

1. #### Selecting Option based on its *value*

   ```
   var vals = [2,'c'];

   $('option').each(function(){
      var $t = $(this);

      for (var n=vals.length; n--; )
         if ($t.val() == vals[n]){
            $t.prop('selected', true);
            return;
         }
   });
   ```
2. #### Selecting Option based on its *text*

   ```
   var vals = ['Two','CCC'];                   // what we're looking for is different

   $('option').each(function(){
      var $t = $(this);

      for (var n=vals.length; n--; )
         if ($t.text() == vals[n]){            // method used is different
            $t.prop('selected', true);
            return;
         }
   });
   ```

---

#### Supporting HTML

```
<select>
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
   <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select>
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="a">AAA</option>
   <option value="b">BBB</option>
   <option value="c">CCC</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This example is very useful.  I wasn't sure how to iterate through the options and set the selected attribute.  Thank you for such a complete answer.

Comment: No problem llihttocs, be sure to click the up arrow next to questions/comments you find helpful.  And select the checkmark next to the answer you choose. -- you can do either w/o it costing you anything

Answer (score 1):

Excellent answers - here's the D3 version for anyone looking:

```
<select id="sel">
    <option>Cat</option>
    <option>Dog</option>
    <option>Fish</option>
</select>
<script>
    d3.select('#sel').property('value', 'Fish');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching I tried @kzh on select list where I only know `option` inner text not `value` attribute, 
this code based on select answer I used it to change select option according to current page `url`on this format 
`http://www.example.com/index.php?u=Steve`

```
<select id="sel">
    <option>Joe</option>
    <option>Steve</option>
    <option>Jack</option>
</select>
<script>
    var val = window.location.href.split('u=')[1]; // to filter ?u= query 
    var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
    var opts = sel.options;
    for(var opt, j = 0; opt = opts[j]; j++) {
        // search are based on text inside option Attr
        if(opt.text == val) {
            sel.selectedIndex = j;
            break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

This  will keeps `url` parameters shown as  selected to make it more user friendly and the visitor knows what page or profile he is currently viewing .

Answer (score 1):

You just write the code

```js
var theVal = 1;

$('#variable_id').val(theVal).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this after updating a register and changed the state of request via ajax, then I do a query with the new state in the same script and put it in the select tag element new state to update the view.

```
var objSel = document.getElementById("selectObj");
objSel.selectedIndex = elementSelected;
```

I hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

`selectElement` is a html `<select>` element.

Increment the value:

```
selectElement.selectedIndex++
```

Decrement the value:

```
selectElement.selectedIndex--
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var accHos = document.getElementById("accHos");
function showName(obj) {
  accHos.selectedIndex = obj.selectedIndex;
 }
```

```css
div {
  color: coral;
}
select {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom:  8px;
  min-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div>Select Account Number:</div>
<select id="accNos" name="" onchange="showName(this);">
  <option value="">Select Account</option>
  <option value="">1052021</option>
  <option value="">2052021</option>
  <option value="">3052021</option>
  <option value="">4052021</option>
  <option value="">5052021</option>
</select>

<div>Account Holder Name:</div>
<select id="accHos" name="" disabled>
  <option value="">--Name--</option>
  <option value="">Suhan</option>
  <option value="">Cesur</option>
  <option value="">Hopper</option>
  <option value="">Rachel</option>
  <option value="">Arya</option>
 </select>
 <!-- Just for  my referece -->
```

Answer (score -1):

Slightly neater Vanilla.JS version. Assuming you've already fixed `nodeList` missing `.forEach()`:

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach
```

Just:

```
var requiredValue = 'i-50332a31',   
  selectBox = document.querySelector('select')

selectBox.childNodes.forEach(function(element, index){
  if ( element.value === requiredValue ) {
    selectBox.selectedIndex = index
  }
})
```