# How to refresh default display option in select by javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, select

html code:

```
<select>
    <br>
    <option>1</option><br>
    <option>2</option><br>
</select>
```

This select will default display the first option item(display 1).
Now i want to change select to display the second item by jquery when dom is ready, but i tried several times, all failed.The following is my attempt:

1. $('select').prop('selectIndex', 1);
2. $('option').eq(1).attr('selected', 'selected');
3. $('option').eq(1).prop('selected', true);
4. default set select's style to 'display:none' in html code, then try above three ways and finally invoke $('select').show()

Maybe, i am only setting the dom value, not tell browser to refresh 'select'.

Do you konw the other way to refresh default display option in select?

Comment: The answer is on this post...

[How tochange the selected option][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373058/how-to-change-the-selected-option-of-html-select-element

Comment: the answer is here...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373058/how-to-change-the-selected-option-of-html-select-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `value`s to your options from `select`.

```
<select>
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
</select>
```

Then, just set the value "2".

```
$("select").val("2");
```

Or, you can do this simply setting the second value from `select`.

```
$("select").val(2);
```

See the working example [here](http://goo.gl/pYrak).

Comment: It is effective. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is enough

```
$("select").val(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to select option 2 when page is load.

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option selected="selected">2</option>
</select>
```