# Awesomium change value in select dropdown

Tags: c#, .net, awesomium

I am changing select option using automation in c# by following code.But it doesnt seem to work.

How can we change dropdown value using awesomium.net ?

```
webControl1.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementById("manage").value='x'");
```

Comment: are you trying to set the selected `<option>` of the `<select>` element?  Or are you trying to add a new `<option>`?

Comment: i m trying to change the  selected option @SteveJansen.I want to change the index to some other value.

Answer (score 1):

```
webControl1.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementById('manage').selectedIndex = 1");
```

Or I would something like this because it allows to check that element exists etc.

```
dynamic element = (JSObject) webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementById('manage')");

if (element == null)
    throw new Exception etc.

element.selectedIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery's val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/kaleb/GFS2f/164/):

```cs
webControl1.ExecuteJavascript("$('#manage').value('x');");
```

You can also do this in [plain old Javascript without jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/kaleb/GFS2f/164/).

See [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373058/how-to-change-the-selected-option-of-html-select-element).

Comment: Is Jquery set by default?