# Selecting an option using jquery - select box

Tags: jquery, select

I'm trying to update the selected option in a select box using jQuery. My html is as follows:

```
<select id="selectBox">
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
    <option value="4">Value 4</option>
</select>
```

Using jQuery, how can I change the selected option from the default (first option) to the option with value 3 (third option)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373058/how-to-change-the-selected-option-of-html-select-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#selectBox').val('3')
});
```