# javascript change select option text

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to modify the text of the first select option via javascript. 
But it empties the entire select option

```
 <select name='stuff'>
      <option value="a"> Pepsi </option>
      <option value= "b"> Juice </option>
 </select>


<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementsByName('stuff')[0].innerHTML = "Water";
</script>
```

Comment: If you're just setting text, use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Change The Selected Option of HTML Select Element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373058/how-to-change-the-selected-option-of-html-select-element)

Comment: @NickDugger really? What about **IE8**? :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Depends on his target platform, but then you'd use a combination of innerText and textContent, but innerHTML is hardly appropriate here.

Comment: @NickDugger can you explain why innerHTML is hardly appropriate? And why than a fallback from `textContent` to `innerHTML`?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan innerHTML does trigger a reflow and textContent does not work with IE8>. I'd go with innerText for this one but from a user perspective; he/she won't notice the difference.

Comment: @Frinsh Just for the record, FF does not support innerText, so you would have to do a short polyfill, in which case you should polyfill textContent, and not the other way around.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You want to read from the [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) collection and modify the first element in there:

```
document.getElementsByName('stuff')[0].options[0].innerHTML = "Water";
```

Comment: shouldn't it be: document.getElementsByName('stuff').options[0].innerHTML = "Water";

Comment: @AndreNel Nope, `getElementsByName` returns an array-like object, so you want to pick the first one in that array :)

Comment: Ah of course I see its using getElementsByName I was thinking of getElementById... so I was thinking: document.getElementById('stuff').options[0].innerHTML = "Water"; ... which get one select but on Id and not name rather than what was given: document.getElementsByName('stuff')[0].options[0].innerHTML = "Water"; ... sorry... :)

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
 $('select[name=stuff] option:first').html("abcd");
```

Comment: OP did not ask for jQuery, nor does this question have the jQuery tag.

Comment: Same question and I want to use to jQuery - thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
 <select name='stuff'>
          <option id="first" value="a"> Pepsi </option>
          <option value= "b"> Juice </option>
     </select>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = "Water";
    </script>
```

Comment: also works : document.getElementById("first").text= "Water";