# How to refresh select without refreshing full page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

Hello i want to refresh this select without refreshing all page

```
<select name="number" id="number">
             <option value="1">first</option>
             <option value="2">second</option>
             <option value="3">third</option> 
</select>
```

I had reset it because I needed it to perform a few tasks but to update it as in the beginning, I have to update all my page but I just want to refresh the combobox itself without having to refresh the page. What code should I put ?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373058/changing-the-selected-option-of-an-html-select-element

Comment: @admcfajn I do not need to change the elements but I just want to reset the select as it was. There is no way to update a select?

Comment: I checked the link but it is not the same problem

Comment: That's 100% how you do it. You'd use javascript to select the element and then change it's value. Now, I may have misunderstood you... Adding `<option value="1" selected>first</option>` would keep that one selected after refresh, in case a different selection had been made & was being stored by the browser.

Comment: You did not understand me! The form is empty when I click on the empty button and after clicking on the add button it remains empty until I have refreshed the page but I want that when I click on the add button it loads As default

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't solve that problem by only seeing the html. I'd need to see the code relevant to the add-button to help you find a solution.

Comment: *«when I click on the add button it loads As default»* -- So show the HTML for the «add» button. Show the HTML for the «empty» button aswell. If that is more simple, show HTML for the whole form. **And show the JS scripts** you actually have.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reset the selection, please try this.

```
$('#number').val('');
```

Or

```
$('select option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
```

If you want to remove all the option from the dropdown and make it empty, try this.

```
$('#number').empty();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one 'select' you can always create a function and use this:

```
const selects = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('select'); 
selects.forEach(select => {
   select.value = '';
});
```