# How To Make Arrows To Change Selected Option For Drop Down

Tags: javascript, html

If I have a drop down menu like the following:

```
<select>
    <option>Dog</option>
    <option>Cat</option>
    <option>Bird</option>
</select>
```

How could I create two buttons that when pressed would change the chosen option? So if `Cat` was selected and the up arrow was pressed, `Dog` would become selected. The same would happen for a down arrow. When `Dog` was selected and the down arrow is clicked `Cat` would become selected.

Comment: If the up arrow is pressed when the selection is dog, should it go to the other end of the collection, or do nothing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the selected option of an HTML Select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373058/changing-the-selected-option-of-an-html-select-element)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service. The objective here is for you to research the basics and when you have code that doesn't work as expected others help fix **your code**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
var ddl = document.getElementById("s")

function change(x) {
  if (x.value === 'down') {
    ddl.selectedIndex = ddl.selectedIndex + 1
  } else {
    ddl.selectedIndex = ddl.selectedIndex - 1
  }
};
```

```html
<select id="s">
  <option>Dog</option>
  <option>Cat</option>
  <option>Bird</option>
</select>
<input id="d" type="button" value="down" onclick="change(this); return false;">
<input id="u" type="button" value="up" onclick="change(this); return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#up").click(function(){
var selecteddata = $("#data option:selected").val();
  var next = parseInt(selecteddata)-1;
  $("#data").val(next.toString());
});

$("#down").click(function(){
var selecteddata = $("#data option:selected").val();
  var next = parseInt(selecteddata)+1;
  $("#data").val(next.toString());
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="data">
<option value="0">Dog</option>
<option value="1">Cat</option>
<option value="2">Bird</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="UP" id="up" />
<input type="button" value="Down" id="down" />
</body>
</html>
```