# how can i change selection list to links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how can I change dynamic select options into links?

```
<select id="input-sort" class="form-control" onchange="location = this.value;">
   {% for sorts in sorts %}
   {% if sorts.value == '%s-%s'|format(sort, order) %}
   <option value="{{ sorts.href }}" selected="selected">{{ sorts.text }}</option>
   {% else %}
   <option value="{{ sorts.href }}">{{ sorts.text }}</option>
   {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```

which gives the result as

Select the option...

- List item 1
- List item 2
- List item 3
- List item 4

where I want to be

select: **List item 1**  **List item 2**  **List item 3**  **List item 4**

Here I found this question similar to mine but it is not working in my condition
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373058/changing-the-selected-option-of-an-html-select-element)
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966637/how-can-i-change-select-tag-option-into-button-group)

Comment: `<select>` is an interactive tag and so is a `<button>`/`<input type='button'>`. An interactive tag cannot be nested within another interactive tag.  The browser will remove the nested tag (i.e. buttons will be removed automatically.) Furthermore, the only tags allowed as a child to `<select>`  are `<option>` and `<optgroup>`.

Comment: @zer00ne then there is no solution for this?

Comment: Yes sir, you'll need to make a customized drop down menu made of some other tags like `<div>` or better yet a `<details>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('option');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var btn = document.createElement('input');
    btn.type = 'button';
    btn.value= elements[i].value;
    console.log(btn);
    document.getElementById('input-sort').appendChild(btn);
}
```

Comment: does it change selection list to buttons?

Comment: i think you can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373058/changing-the-selected-option-of-an-html-select-element

Comment: I read that before posting but that answer not helping me my content `{{ sorts.href }}` keep changes when clicking other checkboxes.